# how to run all nightwatch tests from one file?

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

I have a folder that contains many folders. Each folder contains a test file. How can I have one main file that says which other files it should run in nightwatch?

Answer (score 0):

Tags are the typical way to select a subset of tests to run; these are documented at http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-tags

If you really want a file listing the tests to run (say, one per line) just give its contents to Nightwatch on the command line, as if you had typed each test filename:

```
nightwatch $(cat files_to_run.txt)
```